# Given start times and duration, show duration since started for every minute on the minute

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Background:**
I have several hardware devices (controllers) to which commands are being sent when an operator presses a button on a web page. We are investigating why sometimes the communication is slow. I set up a python automated script to scrape the page and change controller modes every minute on three separate controllers. I log the beginning of the operation and the duration.

**Sample Data:**

```
Id  Cont_id Start_time (pst)    Duration (sec)
316 11002   2017-06-22 20:05:13 5
317 6224    2017-06-22 20:05:38 15
319 7782    2017-06-22 20:06:20 15
318 11002   2017-06-22 20:06:20 5
320 6224    2017-06-22 20:06:56 15
321 11002   2017-06-22 20:07:27 5
336 7782    2017-06-22 20:07:38 500
322 6224    2017-06-22 20:08:14 15
323 11002   2017-06-22 20:08:36 5
324 6224    2017-06-22 20:09:32 10
325 11002   2017-06-22 20:09:43 10
326 6224    2017-06-22 20:10:44 10
327 11002   2017-06-22 20:10:55 10
328 6224    2017-06-22 20:11:56 5
329 11002   2017-06-22 20:12:07 15
330 6224    2017-06-22 20:13:03 10
```

**Desired Results:**
I'd like to have a report that has an entry for every minute and tells me how long each controller has been in its current operation. For example, consider around the time ~20:07 in the sample data (controller 7782). I would like to see the following;

```
sample_time | cont_id | last_start_time | time_in_operation
20:08:00*   | 7782    | 20:07:38        | 22
20:08:00    | 11002   | 20:07:27        | 5 *
20:08:00    | 6224    | 20:06:56        | 15
20:09:00    | 7782    | 20:07:38        | 88
20:09:00    | 11002   | 20:08:36        | 5
20:09:00    | 6224    | 20:08:14        | 15
20:10:00    | 7882    | 20:07:38        | 148
....etc
```

- Note1: I show time for brevity - I actually want the entire date/time
  Note2: This is 5 seconds because the operation is done, so use the 
       duration value.

**Question:** My biggest problem is coming up with a mock entry every minute. Once that is solved, I think I can get the rest...So, how do I write a query that gives me an entry for every minute between two time ranges, written in a way that I can use to calculate the final report as per the sample data.

**Setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.operationtimelog (
    id int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('operationtimelog_id_seq'::regclass),
    controller_id int4 NOT NULL,
    op_start_time timestamp NOT NULL,
    op_duration int4 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT operationtimelog_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
);

insert into
    operationtimelog (controller_id, op_start_time, op_duration) values
    (11002,  '2017-06-22 20:05:13', 5),
    (6224,   '2017-06-22 20:05:38', 15),
    (7782,   '2017-06-22 20:06:20', 15),
    (11002,  '2017-06-22 20:06:20', 5),
    (6224,   '2017-06-22 20:06:56', 15),
    (11002,  '2017-06-22 20:07:27', 5),
    (7782,   '2017-06-22 20:07:38', 500),
    (6224,   '2017-06-22 20:08:14', 15),
    (11002,  '2017-06-22 20:08:36', 5),
    (6224,   '2017-06-22 20:09:32', 10),
    (11002,  '2017-06-22 20:09:43', 10),
    (6224,   '2017-06-22 20:10:44', 10),
    (11002,  '2017-06-22 20:10:55', 10),
    (6224,   '2017-06-22 20:11:56', 5),
    (11002,  '2017-06-22 20:12:07', 15)
```

Comment: I don't get logic, why you must get that  Desired Result  for entry id 336

Comment: @OtoShavadze : Thank you...If you didn't understand it others wont as well. I've updated the desired results, please let me know if that gives sufficient clarity.

Comment: @SteveJ since you updated your question with the solution, please include `select * from durations` at the end to make it work :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question: given two timestamps generate a table which holds records for every minute between them.

```
select time_column 
from generate_series(
  '2017-06-22 20:00:00'::TIMESTAMP, 
  '2017-06-22 20:09:00'::TIMESTAMP, 
  '1m'
) x(time_column)
```

Output:

```
     time_column
---------------------
 2017-06-22 20:00:00
 2017-06-22 20:01:00
 2017-06-22 20:02:00
 2017-06-22 20:03:00
 2017-06-22 20:04:00
 2017-06-22 20:05:00
 2017-06-22 20:06:00
 2017-06-22 20:07:00
 2017-06-22 20:08:00
 2017-06-22 20:09:00
```

---

Then you can use a `LEFT JOIN` to connect your table/query to it by that time column with truncation of seconds for `op_start_time` from your sample data.

How to truncate seconds from a timestamp?

```
select date_trunc('m','2017-06-22 20:07:38'::timestamp)
```

Output:

```
     date_trunc
---------------------
 2017-06-22 20:07:00
```

Comment: That is the piece I was looking for - thanks. I'll take that and run with it and post back if I get stumped. If it works, I think I should edit the question to get rid of the extra and mark this as the answer.

Comment: Sure, I didn't even dig into your statement logic since I found the question and additional context made it fuzzy for me.